# Insert into same table avoiding duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

```
Table enrollments
-----------------

id      classId     userId
--      -------     ------
1         1           1
--      -------     ------
```

after this stats: want to reject inserting whenever again inserting { `classId=1`, `userId=1` }

If user inserts same `classId` and `userId` then it should rejects inserting.
I've already tried:

```
INSERT INTO enrollments(classId, userId) 
    VALUES('{$classId}', '{$userId}')
    WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM 
                enrollments WHERE 
                    classId='{$classId}' AND userId='{$userId}')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `classId` and `userId` are combined as unique, so same `classId` and `userId` can't be inserted if it exists previously in table.

```
ALTER TABLE enrollments
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Person UNIQUE (classId,userId);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of below Code

```
INSERT INTO enrollments(classId, userId) 
    VALUES('{$classId}', '{$userId}')
    WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM 
                enrollments WHERE 
                    classId='{$classId}' AND userId='{$userId}')
```

replace with

```
INSERT INTO enrollments(classId, userId) 
    SELECT '{$classId}', '{$userId}'
    WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM 
                enrollments WHERE 
                    classId='{$classId}' AND userId='{$userId}')
```

Example : you can try with demo data

```
INSERT INTO enrollments(classId, userId) 
    SELECT 2, 2
    WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM 
                enrollments WHERE 
                    classId=2 AND userId=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use INSERT IGNORE rather than INSERT

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO person_tbl (classId, userId)
VALUES( '{$classId}', '{$userId}')
```

Note: On duplicate insertion, this statement won't generate an error.

Answer (score -1):

Remove id and set classId and userId as primary.
Then just do a normal insert, if they exist it will not be inserted again.

Answer (score -1):

if you want avoiding duplicate then make these fileds(classId, userId) UNIQUE key or you want these fileds are not null also then you can make these these fields as PRIMIRY key.

Answer (score -1):

Make id as primary and combine id and classid as unique. It will prevent from inserting duplicate from the sql end.

Answer (score -1):

```
create table enrollments
(
classId int,
userId int
)

ALTER TABLE enrollments
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Person UNIQUE (classId,userId);

INSERT INTO enrollments(classId, userId) 
    VALUES(1, 1);
```

where clause cannot be entered in insert statement, try this code .the above table structure will not be allow to insert  duplicate entry